# How to enable more uart port on raspberry pi 4 ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: boot, pi-4, ubuntu, uart

I recently got the Raspberry Pi 4 for a university project. I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on it. Now I am trying to enable a second `uart` port because for the project I need to connect multiple sensors via `uart`. But after I set `dtoverlay=uart4` in `usercfg.tx`t, the system got stuck on the rainbow splash screen. I disabled Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, `spi`, and `i2c`, but it didn't help.

Do you guys have any suggestions what I can try?

Comment: any reason you use uart4 rather than, say uart1?

Comment: uart0 and uart1 use the same pins. So i can choose only from uart2 to uart5. But unfortuanally they wont work ...

Comment: Ubuntu Server is limited to what Canonical choose to include - many of Raspbian's features are omitted. You might be able to copy the Device Tree overlay and kernel modules from Raspbian.

Comment: yeah in /boot/firmware/overlays there are some like disable-bt and disable-wifi. But there are also uart0 - 5. So why should ubuntu ship them when they dont work.

Comment: ok i downgraded to ubuntu 19.10.1 and it works as intended. why not in 20.04?

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it by downgrading to 18. quite annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently tested it again. It works fine now. :)

Comment: To improve your answer, can you clarify what you did to resolve this?  Is this working for you on 20.04?  Did you make any changes to get it working?

Comment: I just updated Ubuntu and it now works exactly as it did in 19.10.1.